# C# - Automatically Find imap hostname

Tags: c#, email, imap

Is this possible? For example, let's say I have a domain "google.com" and I can't find the IMAP hostname for some reason.

Is it possible to find (in this case) imap.gmail.com?
I thought searching for MX DNS records could work here, but realized they aren't the same thing, Like at all.

Comment: Does this help at all:  [Is there a standard DNS record to indicate the IMAP server for a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/814715/is-there-a-standard-dns-record-to-indicate-the-imap-server-for-a-domain)

Comment: @Amy From what I can tell, SRV records dont work, If you try do a lookup it doesnt show em

Comment: [This is how Thunderbird does it.](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Autoconfiguration)  It describes the algorithm.

Comment: In general, no.  You could use thunderbird's ISPDB, and your own heuristics.

Comment: Since its not really possible in C#, is there some common rules I should try for? At the moment im just doing imap.domain.ext:993 are there other common hostnames and port combinations?